# Spring security OAuth2: permitAll() doesn't work for me (HTTP 401 for unprotected endpoins)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have to add another post to the stack of unaswered ones signaling the same issue. I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and spring-security-oauth2 2.1.5.RELEASE. I have the following resource configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RdfResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
{
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
  {
    httpSecurity
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/, /**/test/**").permitAll()
      .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }
}
```

Based on this configuration I expect that a GET at http://localhost:8080/.../test/ is permitted but it returns HTTP 401:

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

And of course, my Application class declares all the required annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class ReferenceDataFactoryApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run(ReferenceDataFactoryApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder)
  {
    return builder.sources(ReferenceDataFactoryApplication.class);
  }
  ...
}
```

Many thanks in advance for leting me know what I'm doing wrong.

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Comment: Your URL probably doesn't match `/, /**/test/**` pattern. You better split into 2 separate patterns

Comment: This was it, many thanks. However I've seen things like:          
    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll()
Not sure how to vote foe this solution...

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments `”/, /**/test/**”` is not a valid pattern. AntMatcher takes 1 string pattern per method call.

```
.antMatcher(”/”)
.antMatcher(”/**/test/**”)
```

Comment: Yes, this did it, thanks. I voted for your answer but I think 'cause Nikolay Shevchenko only commented. Not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: No its fine, if he writes an answer give him it :) just glad it worked out